# Serializing a JSON file returns null object when acccessing child objects

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I'm trying to read in a local JSON file that contains various objects. But the object always returns null.

I know that the `Resources.Load<TextAsset>(_directory + _fileName).text;` has successfully found the file, since I can output the text to the console.

[image]

My goal is to be able to ask for a key and get back the value for the selected language. ie: `hello_world.sp` would return `Hola, mundo`.

However, anytime I go to access any object like `Debug.Log(lang.languageList.Count);` I get the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

Eventually, I would like to be able to add additional language values, `fr`,`it`, etc...

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**lang.json**

```
{
  "hello_world": {
    "en": "Hello, World!",
    "sp": "Hola, mundo"
  },
  "button_ok": {
    "en": "Yes",
    "sp": "Si"
  },
  "button_cancel": {
    "en": "Cancel",
    "sp": "Cancelar"
  }
}
```

**JSONLoad.cs**

```
public class JSONLoader
{
    private static readonly string _directory = "Langs/";
    private static readonly string _fileName  = "lang";

    private string ReadJsonFile() { return Resources.Load<TextAsset>(_directory + _fileName).text; }

    public void Load()
    {
        var file = ReadJsonFile();
        var lang = JsonUtility.FromJson<LanguageObject>(file);

        Debug.Log(lang);
    }
}

    [Serializable]
    public class LangValue
    {
        public string en { get; set; }
        public string sp { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LangKey
    {
        public string          id       { get; set; }
        public List<LangValue> children { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class LanguageObject
    {
        public List<LangKey> languageList { set; get; }
    }
```

Comment: Im sure properties arent supported..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json structure doesn't match your classes. It's not a list. Here's a working example:

Json:

```
{
    "languageList": 
     [
        {
            "id": "hello_world",
            "children": {
                "en": "Hello, World!",
                "sp": "Hola, mundo"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "button_ok",
             "children": {
                "en": "Yes",
                "sp": "Si"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "button_cancel",
            "children": {
                "en": "Cancel",
                "sp": "Cancelar"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Classes:

```
[Serializable]
public class LangValue
{
    public string en;
    public string sp;
}

[Serializable]
public class LangKey
{
    public string id;
    public LangValue children;
}

[Serializable]
public class LanguageObject
{
    public List<LangKey> languageList;
}
```

PS: I'm not a fan of `JsonUtility` I'd rather go for `Json.Net` which allows the use of properties among other things.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html), JSON serialization using `UnityEngine.JsonUtility` relies on models having public *fields*, not *properties*. You'll need to define your models with fields instead of properties.

Ie.,

```
[Serializable]
public class LangValue
{
    public string en;
    public string sp;
}

[Serializable]
public class LangKey
{
    public string id;
    public List<LangValue> children;
}

[Serializable]
public class LanguageObject
{
    public List<LangKey> languageList;
}
```

Comment: *facepalm* I can't believe I didn't catch that. I have been pulling my hair out all morning. Thank you.

Comment: @user-44651 that's not gonna work either, the problem is your json doesnt match the class structure you're trying to deserialize it into. It doesn't even contain a list/array!